Detaching a thread versus calling pthread_exit() from main(), consequences for resources and memory in both scenarios
I'm fairly new to C programming and am at the moment trying to wrap my head around the pthreads library and threading more generally.
Question 1:
When and why is detaching a thread a nice option to have. It seems like a lot of the things I've read say that detaching a thread is beneficial when you want the thread to live on independently of the main thread. To me this seems to imply that in a lot of the use cases the main thread for whatever reason could be/is usually shorter lived. I'm wondering why it wouldn't be simpler to call pthread_exit() at the end of the main thread, which I believe exits main without killing the process and thereby the remaining thread (through some dark magic that I believe doesn't affect any memory or resources that have been "passed" (not really) from main onto the thread in question), which would effectively achieve the same thing as detaching a thread (?).
Question 2:
Assuming similar if not the same functionality can be achieved using pthread_exit() from main as can be done by detaching a sub-thread. Are there any advantages memory or resource-wise for choosing one over the other. Don't both of these methods effectively do the same thing (i.e. keep the heap and other resources from being cleaned up until all (for pthread_exit() ) or specific (for detached threads) threads have finished.
Cheers for any help.

My suggestion is that you try to work more with the C language, and slowly incorporating third-party libraries into your projects. Threads is an advanced topic, that should be learned rather late.

@Someprogrammerdude I am probably slightly underselling my knowledge of C, I am a student doing my second C programming course (first non-microcontroller based). This is a covered topic however these questions aren't  something they covered in depth (specifically thread detaching).

"some dark magic that I believe doesn't affect any memory or resources that have been passed from main onto the thread in question." Memory, and file descriptors and the like are not passed by "dark magic." In fact they aren't passed at all. Every thread runs in the same virtual address space as every other thread in the same process. A file descriptor that is valid for one thread is valid for every thread in the same process. I'm not sure what other "resources" you might be thinking of, but they probably work the same way.

You're right and I understand 'passing' is a bad way to phrase it (no doubt a residual of us also covering forks() in this course as well). However the dark magic I was referring to was mainly just the OS keeping the process alive after main thread has returned or exited (via either pthread_exit() or having a detached thread still running). I mentioned resources and memory because I did have a followup question which I asked @zwol below, regarding whether the kernel did any cleaning up for resources and memory that may not be accessible to a surviving thread, your response makes me think not.

@noob1232 the dark magic I was referring to was mainly just the OS keeping the process alive ... I think you mean the TCB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_control_block

Q1: I know of two cases where detached threads are useful.
Sometimes you have a secondary thread that executes an infinite loop, and there's no good way to tell that thread that the whole process is about to exit so it should stop.  If the main thread tries to join that thread before exiting, pthread_join will block forever.  If it instead calls exit, or returns from main, without joining the looping thread, that secondary thread will be abruptly killed -- whether or not it's detached.  Detaching that thread declares that you intend to exit out from under it because it can't be joined because it loops forever, it's not a bug.
Sometimes you have a main thread that ought to spend most of its time blocked on an I/O operation, such as accept, and dispatches work to secondary threads.  There is no way to wait for either a thread to be joinable or some other kind of I/O to be ready.  Detaching the secondary threads is one way to make the main thread not need to call pthread_join.
Q1a: In terms of what happens, the only difference between a detached thread, and a non-detached thread that no other thread bothers to join, is that the C library has no way of knowing that nobody’s going to bother to join the non-detached thread, so it won’t free up all the resources associated with that thread when it exits.  It should free most of those resources, but there’s no requirement for it to; in the worst case (if something is continuously creating threads without either detaching or joining them) this could amount to a substantial resource leak.
In the scenario you’re talking about, where main creates a small, fixed number of long-lived threads and then calls pthread_exit, this resource leak isn’t worth worrying about.  However, if I were writing the program, I would still either detach or join all of the threads, for three reasons.  First, it’ll be easier for someone else reading my code (or, for that matter, me reading my code again a couple years from now) to understand that the program is correct if all threads are either detached or joined.  You probably don’t have the experience yet to understand just how important this is, so, exercise for you: dig up a program that you wrote at least six months ago and haven’t touched since, go through it line by line and attempt to explain to another student how it works.  If you haven’t got another student, a rubber duck or stuffed animal will be almost as good.
Second, calling pthread_exit from main means you are abandoning any opportunity to find out if the other threads succeeded in doing what they were supposed to do.  If you instead join all the other threads, then you can have those threads pass back information about
whether they succeeded, and you can aggregate that information into the process’s exit status (the number returned from main).  This is especially important for short-lived programs that might get run from shell scripts, because shell scripts specifically look at process exit statuses to detect when some operation failed.
Third, a program that creates N long-lived threads from main and then calls pthread_exit can always be restructured to create N − 1 long-lived threads from main and then do whatever the Nth thread was going to do directly in the main thread, which is slightly more efficient and may be easier to understand.  This isn’t nearly as important as the other two reasons, though.
Q2: Indeed, in general, short-lived programs need not bother with fine-grained resource deallocation and in fact it's often more efficient not to clean things up on the way out.  (The time cost of calling free for tens of thousands of small allocations, for instance, can be substantial, and all that work is redundant to the OS erasing the entire address space when the process exits.)
People will tell you sternly never to skip that work; this is because you want to be in the habit of carefully managing resources so you don't mess it up when you do write a long-lived program.  But once you get into that habit, it's completely fine to decide on purpose to skip the cleanup for a program that does its thing and exits.
Q3: When you call pthread_exit, only the calling thread is terminated (even if it’s the main thread).  If the thread is detached, all of the resources associated directly with the thread are freed at this point.  If it’s not detached, a small amount of data has to be preserved until someone joins the thread, but most of the resources should be freed immediately.  (As I mentioned above, though, there’s no actual requirement for any of it to be freed until the thread is joined.  This is because it’s actually quite difficult to free as much as possible as soon as the thread exits!  Ask a separate question about that if you want to know why.)
Thing is, though, there aren’t very many “resources associated directly with a thread.”  The biggest item is the thread’s stack.  There’s also a chunk of memory called a “thread control block” or “thread descriptor,” and there may be some kernel resources: a “light weight process,” whatever that means on your OS, and maybe some locks and stuff.
Basically all other resources are associated with the process and don’t get deallocated until explicitly released or the entire process exits.  Important things that will not get deallocated when a thread exits, even if the remaining threads cannot access them anymore, include:

Open files
Memory allocated with malloc and friends
Memory mappings (mmap)
Locks held by the exited thread
The program’s code
Global data


@noob1232 Yeah, I hit the post button on accident well before I was done.  I've finished writing everything I wanted to write now.  Let me know if there's anything that still doesn't make sense.

Cheers for the thorough answer. I do have questions regarding the example you gave which I think I rather poorly outlined in my initial question. In the infinite loop example, wouldn't calling pthread_exit() from main make the need to join or detach the infinite thread redundant (i.e. pthread_exit() would only be called at the end of the main program and wouldn't incur any unnecessary blocking and also wouldn't kill of the process, thereby allowing the infinite thread to continue and main to finish).

Also do you know if calling pthread_exit() keeps all program memory and resources from being cleaned up or does the OS somehow determine which ones are reachable from the surviving thread/s and cleans up the rest?

@noob1232 Revised to address your follow-up questions.

Usually threads communicate with each other so normally there is always aa way to tell the thread that now  is the time to terminate

Thank you, you've answered everything I've asked and more in depth and also given me other questions to ponder (e.g. difficulty of freeing of memory and resources once a thread has finished and several others)

@0___________ Several times I have written a thread that just does for (;;) { sleep(interval); do_periodic_task() } and plumbing in a "you're done, exit" event would have been substantially more work than just detaching the thread and exiting the process out from under it.

There is no way to wait for either a thread to be joinable or some other kind of I/O to be ready. <- this is untrue; you can design the child thread's event-loop to use non-blocking I/O and block only inside select(), and have the main thread notify the child thread that it is time to exit now, just before the main thread calls pthread_join() (e.g. by send it a byte on a pipe you created for that purpose, that it is also select()-ing on)

@JeremyFriesner That workaround is applicable at least sometimes, but it doesn't change the fact that with pthreads there is no way to do a select-like operation where some of the handles to wait for are file descriptors and others are pthread_t's.

@zwol right, that is why you do your select-like operation by calling select() instead.  Is there a particular scenario where that can't be done?

@JeremyFriesner ... Any situation where some of the handles you need to wait for are pthread_t's (or condition variables, semaphores, process IDs, etc. etc.) instead of file descriptors? I run into this situation about once every other program I write, so it feels completely obvious to me, what part of it isn't clear to you?

@zwol I run those situations regularly as well, and in each case I solve the problem using the self-pipe technique I mentioned in my comment above.  You commented "that workaround is applicable sometimes, but it doesn't change the fact [...]", which maybe implies that you know of use-cases where it cannot be used and therefore the programmer is forced to detach the thread instead.  Are there such cases?  All I can think of is that you maybe don't have control over the part of the code that would need to call send() on the pipe to notify select().

@JeremyFriesner There are workarounds, yes, but they are workarounds.  Unix ought to have an equivalent of Windows' WaitForMultipleObjects (only even more general), but it doesn't. That's all I am saying.


Question 1: When and why is detaching a thread a nice option to have.

The main thing achieved by detaching a thread is that the system automatically cleans up its resources when it terminates, without waiting for another thread to join it.  This is useful in a process that launches subsidiary jobs in threads, but does not care when or if they finish.  The system will automatically clean up those threads' resources without any other thread having to manage that.  The jobs might be either long- or short-lived.
The main cost is the dual: you cannot join a detached thread to await its completion.
You rarely want to detach threads, if only because you almost always do want to, at some point, await their completion.

It seems like a lot of the things I've read say that detaching a thread is beneficial when you want the thread to live on independently of the main thread.

Independence from other threads, yes, in a sense.  Continuing to run past their termination, not necessarily. It is not necessary to detach a thread for that thread to remain alive after the initial thread terminates, and there's no special advantage to detaching a thread that intends to do so.

To me this seems to imply that in a lot of the use cases the main thread for whatever reason could be/is usually shorter lived.

I don't think that is a valid conclusion.

I'm wondering why it wouldn't be simpler to call pthread_exit() at the end of the main thread, which I believe exits main without killing the process and thereby the remaining thread (through some dark magic that I believe doesn't affect any memory or resources that have been "passed" (not really) from main onto the thread in question), which would effectively achieve the same thing as detaching a thread (?)

It does not achieve the same thing as detaching a thread.
If control returns from initial execution of main() -- by executing a return statement or by reaching the closing } of the main()'s definition -- then the system behaves as if the exit() function had been called, which kills all remaining threads of the process, whether joinable or detached.  Although this is the overwhelmingly prevalent case, it is in a sense the special one.
If the initial thread terminates without explicitly or implicitly calling exit(),* then you get normal thread-termination semantics.  The primary way to achieve this is for the initial thread to call pthread_exit().  Not much magic there.  You just get the same thing that happens whenever any other thread terminates.  The initial thread can even be joined if its thread id has been made available, and it has not been detached itself.  All other live threads continue to run, whether they are joinable or detached.

Question 2: Assuming similar if not the same functionality can be achieved using pthread_exit() from main as can be done by detaching a sub-thread.

The assumption is not valid, so the question is moot.  Do note, however, that pthreads does not have "sub-threads"; rather, all threads are peers.  Among other things, any thread can join any joinable thread other than itself, regardless of which thread started which.

*except when killed by a signal whose disposition is process termination.
